# Whats the point of using the latest API?

Tags: android

So I'm new to android development and I recently did some development that used API 11.  If every android cannot upgrade to the latest API, then what is the point of developing with the latest API?  It would only be compatible with a few phones.

Answer (score 3):

It's a trade-off. Later APIs tend to have more features which will make your life easier, or the application better.

However, since many devices are unable to run later APIs, your target market is smaller.

You should choose the API that's going to return most profit. That's a balancing act since earlier APIs may make the development process harder, longer and more expensive, even though they have more devices.

Similarly, I've actually developed software for specific screen sizes since there's *no* possibility my app would look good on a phone, hence no point in me trying. I have foregone the possible market space to (1) make it look good on tablets; and (2) speed my development time.

Answer (score 2):

In general you should select the minimum API level that gives you all the functionality you need for your application in order to maximize compatibility.

The newer APIs support newer hardware and software features. But the downside as you noted is that most devices will not be running at that version.

So it all depends on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what @MikyDinescu said, this is mostly my thoughts & theory as I am relatively new to Android as well, but it seems that it would give more reason to own a Nexus device which gets the latest updates immediately. Also, I would think that if developers are pushing new features to their apps for the latest API then it will push carriers/companies to get the latest Android updates to their devices for users.

Comment: I also would highly agree with @paxdiablo.

Answer (score 0):

Latest APIs would have more features. Android is improving with each version, and APIs are getting better while some are deprecated. By using new API, it will help down the line to follow recommended and newer patterns should you decide to appeal to a larger market (which you eventually will when the old phones are obsolete).

I like to use latest APIs so that the people with the latest supported phones could have the latest features (such as rich/expandable notification in Jellybean). This can be a simple if-else version check.